# How to use redux-persist v5?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-persist

I started to learn redux and try to use redux-persist to store data. Since redux-persist was update to v5 now and recommend to use PersistGate. But I could found few documents about PersistGate. I write some code but this error occured `PersistGate(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null.` This is my code:

store.js

```
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import { createLogger } from 'redux-logger'
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux'
import { persistStore, persistCombineReducers } from 'redux-persist'
import storage from 'redux-persist/es/storage'
import reducer from '../reducers'

const loggerMiddleware = createLogger()

const middleware = [thunk, loggerMiddleware]

const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose

const configureStore = composeEnhancers(
  applyMiddleware(...middleware),
)(createStore)

const config = {
  key: 'root',
  storage,
}

const combinedReducer = persistCombineReducers(config, reducer)

const createAppStore = () => {
  let store = configureStore(combinedReducer)
  let persistor = persistStore(store)

  return { persistor, store }
}

export default createAppStore
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import './assets/css/index.css'
import App from './App'
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import createAppStore from './store'
import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/es/integration/react'

const { persistor, store } = createAppStore()

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <PersistGate persistor={persistor}>
      <App />
    </PersistGate>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root'))
registerServiceWorker()
```

compiler throws error in render(). Error message as above. 
Would you please tell me how to use PersistGate correctly? Or where could I find more documents or examples? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

If add loading state `<Loading />` (which is ur component like spinner or greeking component, it defines the way the app looks when loading data from storage) in `PersistGate` still not working.

Please confirm that your reducer
`import reducer from '../reducers'`, should be the raw reducer (javascript object), do not apply `combineReducers` (redux), if you already applied it, then in ur `store.js`, you should use `persistReducer` instead of `persistCombineReducers` as follows

```
import { persistReducer } from 'redux-persist'
...
...
const combinedReducer = persistReducer(config, reducer)
...
...
```

Probably it will help fix the problem, if not, please leave a message

Comment: Thank you for reply. I updated to v5.2.2 and <Loading> is optional now. I just not use it.

Comment: That's what I was making mistake at. Had reducers already combined and was passing it to persistCombineReducer. Thanks for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

I know the reason. In v5.2.0 loading is required. Like this:

```
render() {
  return (
    <PersistGate 
      persistor={persistor} 
      loading={<Loading />}
      >
    <PersistGate persistor={persistor}>
      {/* rest of app */}
    </PersistGate>
  )
}
```

It's optional now in v5.2.2